# Grothendieck group of $\mathbb P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

I am trying to prove that the Grothendieck group $K_0(\mathbb P^n)$ is generated by $\{\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1),...,\mathcal O(n)\}$.

I already showed that this set generates a full sublattice of $K_0(\mathbb P^n)$.
For this I showed via induction that the rank is bounded above by $n+1$ and then I defined the function:

$\phi:G_0(\mathbb P^n)\times G_0(\mathbb P^n) \rightarrow \mathbb Z$

$(\mathcal F,\mathcal G) \mapsto \chi(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G^{\vee})$

where $\chi$ denotes the Euler characteristic.

Using this function I defined the matrix $\varPhi$ by 
$\varPhi_{i,j}:=\phi(\mathcal O(i),\mathcal O(j))$.

How can I proceed from here that the $\mathcal O(i)$ actually generate the Grothendieck group?

Sincerely, slinshady

Edit: Maybe I should say that I only consider locally free $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}$ -modules, as this is sufficient in sufficiently nice settings.

Comment: Why don't you use the projective bundle formula?

Comment: are you referring to the formula stated here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236264/geometric-proof-for-the-projective-bundle-formula-in-k-theory ?

Comment: See e.g. p. 142, Theorem 2.1 in Quillen's *Higher Algebraic $K$-theory*.

Comment: @slinshady Take the projective bundle of the vector bundle $k^{n+1} \to \text{Spec}(k)$ and apply the formula

Comment: thank you. This gave me some insight into higher K theory. I just dealt with the problem by Serre's theorem about coherent sheaves (so the $\mathcal O(k)$, all $k$ have to be generators) and the Koszul complex of the affine plane together with twisting gives us, that the $\mathcal O(k)$ are generate by those with $-n\leq k \leq 0$.